# Why use .h1 instead of actual h1?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Within the Bootstrap CSS project](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less), styles are provided for your heading tags (H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6), but there's also a series of class names based on the headings as well (.h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6). What is the benefit gained from using the class name of a H1 without properly using the H1 tag? I would think that you always want to make sure your HTML mirrors your visual importance.

Any thoughts explaining a good reason for using .h1 instead of using a h1 tag would be appreciated.

Comment: That’s a good question because I honestly can’t think of a reason to do this. But Bootstrap is somewhat known for advertising unsemantic code…

Comment: Bootstrap also abuses the `<i>` element to mean *icon*, I'd assume that anything that doesn't appear to make sense is them being crap.

Comment: maybe so you can add the class to a div or span?

Comment: @PedroEstrada — But why use `<div class="h1">` instead of `<h1>`?

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: That just makes it even more redundant.

Comment: @RahulTripathi Writing the same thing as a comment instead of an answer does not really make it better. The point of the question is why one would use a class selector when there is an actual element that carries semantic information.

Comment: In html standards are in the eye of the beholder, rather than set in stone. Bootstrap is trying to give more flexibility in design you in particular might use, without forcing a particular view of what is proper. This is probably not the best type of question for stackoverflow as it is more opinion based rather than factual.

Comment: @scrappedcola - the answer could be it's a personal preference. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You ask:

> Why use `.h1` instead of actual `h1`?

#### Short answer:

The goal is to use both, together.

The usefulness of the `.h*` classes comes into play when the size of the typography in the design does not correlate with the semantically appropriate heading levels. By splitting the problem in two, we can cleanly solve for both.

The first bit is the element/tag. The '`<h*>`' takes care of semantics, accessibility and SEO.

The second bit is the class. The '`.h*`' takes care of visual semantics and typographical hierarchy.

#### Long answer:

I believe that the origins of these classes come from OOCSS project:

[Object-Oriented CSS](http://oocss.org/)

The latest iteration of OOCSS has changed a little since I last looked at it, but here's the relevant `heading.css` file, from an older commit, that has the `.h1` - `.h6` classes that I'm familiar with:

[`6e481bc18f`](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/tree/6e481bc18fea7cae253977ad6b1d9a5bf85a6d24/) [oocss / core / heading / `heading.css`](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/blob/6e481bc18fea7cae253977ad6b1d9a5bf85a6d24/core/heading/heading.css)

From the comments:

> `.h1`-`.h6` classes should be used to maintain the semantically appropriate heading levels - **NOT for use on non-headings**
> ...
> if additional headings are needed they should be created via additional classes, never via location dependant styling

Note the **emphasis above**.

For a good explanation as to why one would use these classes, see:

1. [stubbornella.org](http://www.stubbornella.org): [Don’t Style Headings Using HTML5 Sections](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/09/06/style-headings-using-html5-sections/) (Nicole, the author of this post, is the creator of OOCSS)
2. [csswizardry.com](http://csswizardry.com): [Pragmatic, practical font sizing in CSS](http://csswizardry.com/2012/02/pragmatic-practical-font-sizing-in-css/)
3. [Google Groups › Object Oriented CSS › Headings question: Basic concept/usage?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/object-oriented-css/GE1uzU2Bu48/discussion) (A question I asked back in September of '12)

Relevant quotes from the above links:

#### 1. [stubbornella.org](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/09/06/style-headings-using-html5-sections/)

> ... [HTML5] Section elements are meant to help the browser figure out what level the heading really is, but not necessarily to decide how to style it.
>
> **So, how do we style headings in an HTML5 world?**
>
> ... We shouldn’t use sectioning elements for styling. We should let them do the job they were designed for, which is sorting out the document tree, and solve styling issues another way that meets our goals better: with simple reusable class names that can be applied to any of our headings no matter how deep they may be in the sectioning content.
>
> I recommend abstracting site wide headings into classes because then they are portable, predictable, and dry. You can call them anything you like.

#### 2. [csswizardry.com](http://csswizardry.com/2012/02/pragmatic-practical-font-sizing-in-css/)

> Another absolutely stellar nugget of wisdom [Nicole Sullivan has] given us is what I call double-stranded heading hierarchy. This is the practice of defining a class every time you define a heading in CSS.
>
> ... By assigning a class along with each heading style we now have those styles attached to a very flexible selector that can be moved anywhere, rather than to a very specific and non-movable one.

#### 3. [groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/object-oriented-css/GE1uzU2Bu48/discussion)

Here's a pseudo-html5 usage example (h/t [Jamund Ferguson](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/object-oriented-css/GE1uzU2Bu48/5hTkUaMzd-QJ)):

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Main Heading</h1>
        <section>
            <h1 class="h2">Section Header</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
    <aside class="side">
        <article class="widget">
            <h1 class="h3">Sidebar Headings</h1>
        </article>
        <article class="widget">
            <h1 class="h3">Sidebar Headings</h1>
        </article>
    </aside>
</body>
```

Please read full articles (and thread), via links above, for more detailed information related to this question/topic.

Comment: Wow! What a great answer @mwhulse! That definitely clarifies the practice and helps me understand _why_ I should possibly including this practice into my front-end development.

Comment: Thanks @StephanMuller and @Hynes! More than anything, the [stubbornella.org article](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/09/06/style-headings-using-html5-sections/) (and the [OOCSS code](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/blob/6e481bc18fea7cae253977ad6b1d9a5bf85a6d24/core/heading/heading.css)) really helped to clarify the usage for me ... I'm glad to share the linkage/knowledge.

Comment: This is all interesting information, but I don't at all understand the OOCSS comment "NOT for use on non-headings" - why not? That honestly makes no sense to me.

Comment: @animuson Great question. **My guess:** It's logical. Using `.h1`, for example, on a non-heading could be a little confusing to outsiders (or your future self). Anyway, I don't think there are any hard and fast rules that say you can't use those classes anywhere you please (I personally like restricting their usage to headings only). With that said, instead of take shots in the dark here, I've opted to create a new thread on the OOCSS Google Group: [Object Oriented CSS: Question about heading classes](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/object-oriented-css/xd6uTaTDW_w/discussion).

Comment: @animuson [Nicole Sullivan replied to my/our/your question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/object-oriented-css/xd6uTaTDW_w/r3wpaE37BN8J): **"The strict usage on heading elements was just because I didn't want to see a ton of `<div class="h3">` and have screen reader users and SEO get messed up. If you had giant unimportant text, it would be fine to use those classes on other elements."** Good to know!

Comment: Big ups to @nicole-sullivan for helping to improve my post!

Comment: The place where my approach will break down is when you have widgets you have very little control over, or when you have a widget that is used in multiple places with no markup changes. Sometimes this means that for simple blogs it is best to have separate code for the core content styles and the page chrome like sidebars, headers, footers.

Answer (score 32):

Most stylesheets have a set of font-sizes that correspond with heading styles 1 through 6. Sometimes, elsewhere on the page, web designers want to use those same font sizes on text which should *not* be a part of an actual heading element, for semantic reasons. Rather than providing names for each of those sizes like `.size-12`, `.size-14`, `.size-16`, etc, it's easier just to name them all with class names similar to your headings. That way, you know that the text will be the same size as an H1 element, even though it's not actually an H1 element. I've done this a few times myself.

Comment: +1 you can have text styled like an Hn that isn't an Hn: table caption and legend in a fieldset may easily be styled like an H2 so one just have to add `.H2`

Comment: As I think about it, it would allow you to import existing styles with LESS using .h1(); and then extend the style.

Answer (score 8):

A few reasons I can think of:

- Using div instead of proper tag to get the visual of a header without an impact on SEO
- To avoid complications from browser inconsistencies
- Compatibility with other libraries and frameworks that choose to do the same for reasons 1 and 2
- Design flexibility (as noted by @scrappedcola in the comments)

Answer (score 5):

This allows for a separations of visual hierarchy form semantic hierarchy. eg, I want to tell the viewer one thing, while telling a computer (search engines) something else.

```
<article>
    <h1 class="h1">Page Title</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
    <section>
        <h1 class="h2">Section Heading</h1>
        <div class="h6">Sub Heading</div>
        <p>Some content</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1 class="h2">Section Heading 2</h1>
        <div class="h6">Sub Heading 2</div>
        <p>Some content 2</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

See:

- http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#headings-and-sections (toward the botton of section)
- http://html5doctor.com/html5-seo-search-engine-optimisation/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIn5qJKU8VM

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of offhand is for search engines.  Many will look at an actual h1 tag as the title or subject of a page and use that for searches, etc.  Having multiple h1 tags can confuse the search engine spiders and may screw up searches that would return results for your site (I've also heard it may get you on the "bad site" list with some spiders like Google).

Having the styles allows you to have the same visual look to an element without screwing up search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I have come across recently... this is not particular to Angular but it serves as a good example:

I want to create dynamic/declarative forms in Angular (see Dynamic Forms in the Angular Cookbook) and allow styled text elements. Maximum flexibility would call for allowing me to declaratively add arbitrary HTML elements to my forms, but this is open to scripting attacks, and requires explicit subversion of the Angular compiler to even allow it. Instead, I allow text elements to be added to forms, along with a class for controlling style. So I can use the .h1 style but not the h1 element.

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely help in-terms of SEO and google crawlers to understand your page better.
When it reads h1, it assumes that whatever is in there must be the focal point of the page. H2, would be the second components and so on. This way Google can understand the "scope" of what your page is covering in-terms of content.

Not entirely sure, but a big variable in my opinion would be the "read" mode of pages. This would allow devices and readers to organize content especially for devices used by visually impaired people.

Also it provides structure to the page and a sense of order.